# How to list all created permissions in hasura?

Tags: hasura

I've created a bunch of permissions using hasura and now what to do some querying on them. How do we list all available permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "query," but all the permissions you create are part of Hasura's "metadata". You can export the metadata from Hasura as a YAML file [using the console](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/migrations/manage-metadata.html#exporting-hasura-metadata), or using the CLI:

```
hasura metadata export
```

Either way, you get a YAML representation of your metadata which you can then query using a tool that can parse and query YAML, perhaps something like https://github.com/thedevsaddam/gojsonq.

In terms of SQL querying, Hasura maintains its metadata in the [Postgres database in the `hdb_catalog` schema](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/migrations/reference/how-it-works.html#metadata). You can query the permissions using:

```
select * from hdb_catalog.hdb_permission;
```

Comment: sweet that select statement is what I'm after. thanks!